# Bootstrap button style is different on page

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Anywhere I use a bootstrap button like `<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>` it looks fine and how I want. However I am using the same button on another page within a jQuery UI div. So if I use the button the text is black (should be white) and the colour is off.

I do know I can overwrite the style manually but I'm just wondering does anyone know why this is happening in the first place? Is there anyway I can use the same line as I always do.

Here is an example of how it is written in my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <form>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div class="form-control">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Default instances of jQueryUI and Bootstrap are not compatible. You will need to either manually amend the incompatibilities in the JS and CSS (whatever they are in your case), or alternatively remove one of them and use only a single library for your UI. I would recommend the latter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah thank you, I was thinking Bootstrap and jQueryUI didn't like each other but didn't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn-success{color:#fff;background-color:#28a745;border-color:#28a745}                           
.btn-success:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#218838;border-color:#1e7e34}                    
.btn-success.focus,.btn-success:focus{color:#fff;background-color:#218838;border-color:#1e7e34;box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(72,180,97,.5)}
```

The code was working for me. But if its not working for you, then you can add the above code into the styling directly without removing bootstrap style link.This code does the same styling.

Thankyou